# Parts of mesh go invisible when parenting with automatic weights

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I'm having an issue parenting a mesh to the armature with automatic weights, where upon my attempts of doing so causes parts of the mesh to go completely invisible despite there being bones at those locations as well. 
[image: Before parenting]

[image: After parenting]

Any idea what can be causing this to occur?